# How to deal with nested iframes with Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a daily task, but I got stuck with some nested iframes. The script is working very well till the part of unselecting all document types, it fails.

I tried waiting until the element is clickable. Also, I tried accessing the element with id, css_selector and XPath but nothing helped.

I think the element is located within nested iframes, but can't get the correct sequence.

Here's my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
#options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
#options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-errors"])
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

link = r"https://countyfusion10.kofiletech.us/countyweb/loginDisplay.action?countyname=TylerWV"

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.directory_upgrade":True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled":True,
  "download.prompt_for_download":False,
  "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get(link)

#Login as Guest
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="maindiv"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/input').click()
time.sleep(5)

#Accept Disclaimer
driver.switch_to.frame("bodyframe")
driver.find_element_by_id(r'accept').click()
time.sleep(30)

#Deselect All types
driver.switch_to.default_content()
boxes = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="elemAllNamesJSP_20"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/input[1]')))
print(boxes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you had to switch to the default content, anyway since you got out of the `bodyframe` iframe to access the "boxes" element you have switch to the first parent iframe first, then to the inner parent and then to the inner child. Like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', options=options)
driver.get(link)

#Login as Guest
driver.find_element_by_xpath(r'//*[@id="maindiv"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/center/input').click()

#Accept Disclaimer
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.NAME,"bodyframe"))
driver.find_element_by_id(r'accept').click()

#Deselect All types
driver.switch_to.default_content()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.NAME,"bodyframe"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.NAME,"dynSearchFrame"))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.NAME,"criteriaframe"))
boxes = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,r'//*[@id="elemAllNamesJSP_20"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/input[1]')))
print(boxes)
```

I'm not sure what you trying to achieve by printing the web element "boxes" with `print(boxes)`...
Also I removed the hardcoded delays. Especially the 30 seconds sleep, you don't need it. Use webdriver explicit wait instead.
It will work much faster and still stable.